# ¿Can a subset $\overline{S}$ of the accumulation points of a set S be greater than S itself? in $R^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\overline{S}$ the set of all accumulation points of $S$

Then if $ S \subseteq \overline{S}$.

can $\overline{S}$ be greater than $S$?

Comment: What do you mean by greater than?

Comment: Generally, the inclusion is the other way around, if it exists at all. If $\overline{S} \subseteq S$, then $S$ is a closed set. If $\overline{S} = S$, then $S$ is moreover a "perfect" set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Let $S$ be the open ball of radius $354.8 \sqrt {695} \pi^3$ around the origin.  Then $S \subset \overline S$ ($\overline S$ is the closed ball of the same radius) and the inclusion is strict.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer In Robert's example it's the same.

Comment: @amsmath How do you figure?  I'm using the **open** ball for $S$, so every point on the boundary of the ball is in $\overline S \setminus S$.

Comment: Why do you address me?

Comment: @amsmath I assumed "it's the same" meant you were saying $S=\overline S$ and that you were responsible for the downvote.  Did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Yes, you do. ;-) Before, EeveeTrainer claimed that you consider the closure which is not the set of accumulation points. Then I said it's the same here.

Answer (score 0):

$S =\Bbb Q$ is a mere countable set, while $\overline{S}=\Bbb R$ is uncountable. Most sets are actually smaller then their set of accumulation points.